# Should we have a "Blatantly off-topic close reason?"

Tags: feature-request

Many stack exchange websites have a close reason, "Blatantly off-topic"

UX:

[image]

English:

[image]

Money / Finance:

[image]

We don't have this though. Was there a particular reason why we seem to be in the minority of SE sites that don't have (actually the only one I've seen)? If not I think we should add it. I often find myself wanting to edit the off-topic reason from "...because this question is about" to read "...because this is not about graphic design."

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it's needed as a whole. The clearly off-topic questions are actually few and far between from what I see.

What is needed is to select more then one option for "belongs on other stack site". I just don't feel right sending everything to Meta so mods can sort it out. An auto-comment with link about the other stack site would be beneficial.

Comment: Trying to discuss this in the other meta question I just made ( http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1147/when-can-we-get-other-other-stackexchange-options-in-close-votes ) and in Chat

Comment: I answered the other question but I'll summarize now - volume of migrated questions is not yet high enough to warrant new migration paths. The best way to handle that is to flag for mod attention, or post on meta.

Comment: The best way to get a question migrated is to flag it, usually takes less time.